# Is whatsapp ,messenger ,facebook, skype uses webrtc for audio video streaming (for video confernce) in ios

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, webrtc, jitsi

I am using jitsi- meet for video conferencing app so if I use jitsi-meet URL to load on webview it says "Webrtc is not supported for your browser" , I just want to know what should I use to support webrtc in webview (In Ios swift)

Answer (score 0):

webRTC not supported in the ios webview yet. You will have to use the react-native app/code of jitsi meet.

Comment: yes I am using same jitsi meet code but there is too many error when jitsi frame open in app